# ng-option not selecting the saved value

Tags: angularjs

First of all I am very new at this so I apologize in advance if it is a simple question. I searched whole day yesterday without finding any results. I have following statement

```
<select id="mks" class="form-control"
        ng-options="mkp.MKSProjectID as mkp.MKSProjectName for mkp in MKSProjects"
        ng-model="sel_dvp.MKSProjectID"></select>
```

I also tried

```
<select id="mks" class="form-control"
        ng-options="mkp.MKSProjectID for mkp in MKSProjects"
        ng-model="sel_dvp.MKSProjectID"></select>
```

Which works fine when I select the option and saves it to Sql database. When I retrieve the data the value is not set.To make sure that it is bringing the correct value I did the following.

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
  {{sel_dvp.MKSProjectID}}
</label>
```

and it is showing the correct value. So I am not sure what needs to be done for it to populate the correct value.
Thank you for all the help.

After what j-mean suggested thats how the html look like for select and the second picture is showing the value of seldvp_MKSProjectID[select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx2gm.png)

Comment: What does your `MKSProjects` variable look like? What does your `sel_dvp.MSKProjectID` look like?

Comment: what is `sel_dvp`?  Is this your view model or is this an object stored on your view model that is saved?  I think you are conflicted by what you want to save (an ID) and what is actually persisted

Comment: @devqon -- MKSProjects is objects that has MKSProjectID and MKSProjectName and seldvp_mksProjectID is one of the id that was saved in a table from MKSProjects

Comment: @jusopi yes it is a view model that pull the specific record from table and show it on the page

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just storing `MKSProjectID` at the same $scope level as `MKSProjects`?  What does `sel_dvp` look like?  Is it something more than a simple object?  How does it pull the specific record?

Comment: @jusopi MKSProjects are the list (ID and Desc) for all the projects and selDVP is the return result set of a stored procedure for a particular record.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your model is a string and your option is an object containing that string. Try this:

```
<select id="mks" ng-options="mkp.MKSProjectID  for mkp in MKSProjects" ng-model="sel_dvp" ng-init="sel_dvp.MKSProjectID=MKSProjects[0]" class="form-control"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you but it didnt work. I have another dropdown that works fine so I am totally lost

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('defaultValueSelect', []);
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.MKSProjects =[{MKSProjectID:1,MKSProjectName :"proj1"},
                        {MKSProjectID:3,MKSProjectName:"proj3"},
                        {MKSProjectID:5,MKSProjectName :"proj5"},
                        {MKSProjectID:23,MKSProjectName :"proj23"}] 
    $scope.sel_dvp ={}
    $scope.sel_dvp.MKSProjectID="3";
   //$scope.sel_dvp.MKSProjectID=3;//This will not work
    
 }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.9/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="defaultValueSelect">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <form name="myForm">
            <label for="mySelect">Select Project:</label>


            <select id="mks" class="form-control" ng-model="sel_dvp.MKSProjectID">
                <option ng-repeat="mkp in MKSProjects track by mkp.MKSProjectID" value="{{mkp.MKSProjectID}}">{{mkp.MKSProjectName }}</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <tt>option = {{sel_dvp.MKSProjectID}}</tt><br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try following code

```
<select id="mks" class="form-control" ng-model="sel_dvp.MKSProjectID"> 
   <option ng-repeat="mkp in MKSProjects track by mkp.MKSProjectID" value="{{mkp.MKSProjectID}}">{{mkp.MKSProjectName }}</option> 
</select>
```

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue

Comment: it start to set to the "first value" instead of a selected value. which is an improvment.

Comment: Please can you paste your sel_dvp.MKSProjectID and MKSProjects objects

Comment: There are 143 records that get loaded from database. When i SELECT the record it saves the MKSProjectID in a different table. I am not sure what else can I tell you.

Comment: Okay give me the datatype sel_dvp.MKSProjectID ="1" or sel_dvp.MKSProjectID=1 and MKSProjects =[{MKSProjectID="1",MKSProjectName ="proj1"},..] or MKSProjects =[{MKSProjectID=1,MKSProjectName ="proj1"},..].
Which one is correct?

Comment: Try adding in ng-model toString()

Comment: seldvp_MKSProjectID="1"  and MKSProjects =[{MKSProjectID=1,MKSProjectName ="proj1"},..]. these ones are correct?

Comment: where should i add ng-model to string?

Comment: its saving the value absolutely correct just not setting it when Its load for me. Not sure what I am missing.